# Multiprocessing pool inside a class in python changing array to list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing.pool in python 3 inside a class. This is the original function:

```
stress_matrix, compliance = self.problem.compute_objs(self.xphys)
avg_sm = np.zeros(self.nel)
for i2 in range(self.nel):
    avg_sm = avg_stress_calc(self.xphys, self.nelx, self.nely,
                            self.rmin, stress_matrix, avg_sm, i2)
```

This leaves me with an array with a shape of (16,) and is this:

```
array([0.81814754, 0.64561319, 0.62517261, 0.78422925, 0.6962134 ,
   0.65993462, 0.63970099, 0.68776093, 0.49890513, 0.60900864,
   0.71575952, 0.73120825, 0.32964378, 0.53196899, 0.80481781,
   0.99930964])
```

I tried to speed this up by using multiprocessing pools as my NEL is greater than 10,000 (normally), like so:

```
avgsm = np.zeros(self.nel)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
func = partial(avg_stress_calc, self.xphys, self.nelx,
                       self.nely, self.rmin, stress_matrix, avgsm)
avg_sm = pool.map(func, range(self.nel))
```

For some reason when I do this I get an attribute error: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' and I convert it to an array to get the shape it is (16, 16). The output from the multi-process version looks like this:

```
[array([0.81814754, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.64561319, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.62517261, 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.78422925, 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.6962134, 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ,
   0.       , 0.       , 0.       , 0.       ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.65993462, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.63970099, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.68776093, 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.49890513, 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.60900864,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.71575952, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.73120825, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.32964378, 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.53196899, 0.        ,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.80481781,
   0.        ]), array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
   0.99930964])]
```

I was hoping to use multiprocessing to speed up the for loop as that is the greatest time consumer in my code. Any advice on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the actual Exception output? Explain a litte bit wat do you want to do and say what is partial(...). Also, are you trying to make func a lambda method?

Comment: Edited the orginal post to include the two different outputs from the for loop

Comment: Do you know previously the array's dimmension?

Comment: I use this to start it: avg_sm = np.zeros(self.nel)   I just dont get how it gets switched to list...

Comment: I wrote and example of usage as an answer I'm going to try with a bigger array an will put a working time to each thread and let you know the results

Comment: Looks like your initial for-loop is clobbering `avg_sm` each call? Is that supposed to be `avg_sm[i2]` maybe?

Comment: @I.P.Freeley In the first for-loop no its just a single array output... Its almost as if the np.concatenate is being skipped

Answer (score 0):

`Pool().map()` is good but if you need an object (memory space) to be shared between the different instances you better use threads like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from threading import  Thread
import random
import time

def partial(args, process_id , avg_sm):
    # do some stuff
    print("Th%d - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds"%process_id)
    # do more stuff
    working_time = random.uniform(1,3)
    time.sleep( working_time )
    # write the result
    avg_sm[process_id] = random.uniform(0.0,1.0)
    print("Th%d - Finishing working time from 1 to 3 seconds"%process_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MAX_THREADS = 1000

    nel = 10000

    args = ["some args you define"]
    
    avg_sm = np.zeros(nel) #[0]*nel
    
    process_l = []

    t0 = time.time()

    for pid in range(nel):
        if pid%MAX_THREADS == 0:
            for p in process_l:
                p.join()
        process_l.append( Thread( target=partial, args=( args, pid, avg_sm ) ) )
        process_l[pid].start()
    
    for p in process_l:
        p.join()

    t1 = time.time() - t0
    
    print(avg_sm)

    print("Total computation time: %d s"%t1)
```

PS: you can put as much args as you want, in this example I used a single list named `args`

#### EDIT

A `MAX_THREADS` limit was needed due to memory problems, this you will have to define by yourself. You when this number of created threads are reached (`if pid%MAX_THREADS == 0:`) you will wait until they are finished (maybe you can create a new thread once one or more has finished, that would be more efficient I think). I assumed a delay of 1 to 3 seconds of your method to finish computation time.

Results:

```sh
Th9889 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9988 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9919 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9986 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9866 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9951 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9918 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9991 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9886 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9915 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9996 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9963 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
Th9978 - Starting working time from 1 to 3 seconds
[0.01340808 0.0567745  0.31191508 ... 0.91127015 0.95141791 0.60075809]
Total computation time: 42 s
```